# Spring MVC and login redirect

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a web application, when a use click on a personal profile link, if he is not logged in, I would like to redirect him to login page, then when he logs in, I would to send him back to the link he had originally clicked.

In this case his personal profile.

I have done the part until where redirecting him to login page, but I am trying to find out how to remember his initial click, and redirect to this page after he successfully logs in.

I am using Spring Security for logins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortunately, Spring Security has built-in functionality for remembering the URL that was originally requested, and redirecting your users there after they successfully login.  The quick answer to your question is that you need to enable this functionality by setting the **always-use-default-target** option to false in your Spring Security configuration.

For example, here's a common line from the Spring Security config:

```
<form-login 
    login-page="/login.html"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.html?status=LOGIN_FAILURE"
    default-target-url="/secure/index.html"
    always-use-default-target="false" />
```

This configuration will make the following two flows possible:

**Flow #1**

1. Sally requests /login.html
2. Sally provides a valid username and password
3. Sally is redirected to /secure/index.html, since that is the **default-target-url**

**Flow #2 (The flow you want)**

1. David requests /secure/kittens.html
2. Since David is not logged-in, he is presented with the login page.
3. After providing a valid username and password, David is redirected to /secure/kittens.html, which is the original page he was trying to access.  (He is not taken to the **default-target-url** because **always-use-default-target** is set to false.)

Comment: Does it mean that for any page requested the spring security will start checking if the user has logged in? If not then if you mean to say that only when /secure/kittens.html is requested, the spring will try to check if the user is logged in, i would like to know where or how this check is made? The reason i am asking is i just tested but it did not work, i would like to know if i have to write some redirect logic in /secure/kittens.html?

Comment: i tried return "redirect:signin.htm"; in kittens.html but it did not work

Comment: Does it mean that for any page requested the spring security will start checking if the user has logged in? If not then if you mean to say that only when /secure/kittens.html is requested, the spring will try to check if the user is logged in, i would like to know where or how this check is made? The reason i am asking is i just tested but it did not work, i would like to know if i have to write some redirect logic in /secure/kittens.html?

Comment: This answer coupled with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281901/always-use-default-target-sample  answered my question

Answer (score 5):

For those of you using Spring's `JavaConfig`, the same thing can be achieved using

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         // authentication logic        
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //password encoding logic
        //preferably BCrpyt
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         // @formatter:off
         web.ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/css/**")     //Allow CSS resources.
           .antMatchers("/js/**")      //Allow JavaScript resources.
           .antMatchers("/images/**"); //Allow image resources.
         // @formatter:on
    }        
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")                       //login-page
            .failureUrl("/login.html?status=LOGIN_FAILURE") //authentication-failure-url
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/index.html", false) //default-target-url. set always-use-default-target to `false`
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
}
```

The code snippet above shows a configuration without `XML`.

1. The class is annotated with [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) indicating that

> a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime

2. The class is annotated with [`@EnableWebSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) which adds

> this annotation to an @Configuration class to have the Spring Security configuration defined in any WebSecurityConfigurer

3. This class also extends [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) which

> Provides a convenient base class for creating a WebSecurityConfigurer instance. The implementation allows customization by overriding methods.

4. You can `Autowire` an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` in a public method to handle your authentication needs

I hope this helps for those of you with a similar problem who don't use an `XML` configuration.