# Redirecting user to same location where he came from in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement a functionality so that user after a successful Login should get redirected to same location from where he/she click the Login button.

I am using Spring MVC and for Login in some cases platform is using Spring security and for some third party Login process we are using out own mechanism.

I am wondering, is there any feature either in Spring MVC  or Spring Security so that we can redirect user to same location from where he/she came.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC and login redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267809/spring-mvc-and-login-redirect)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: is there any way to handle this in spring-mvc only?

Comment: No, because the redirect to the login page happens in a Filter, before Spring MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security has provision to redirect the target URL

Have a look [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)
There are four scenarios based on which ss decides on the redirect destination.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @jittakal has answered. I have also used the **SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler** class to redirect to the same view from where user was redirected to the login page.

It is really very easy and awesome feature to use. Go for it. :)