# redirect to the welcome page(login page) whenever any request for .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views folder comes directly

Tags: spring

I am new in spring mvc.i want to redirect to the welcome page(login page) whenever any request for .jsp resources within the `/WEB-INF/views` folder comes directly. I mean without logging into the application.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: Any such request will cause a `404 Not Found` error to be sent back, since WEB-INF is not accessible from the oustide. Why would you want anything other than that?

Comment: Look at [Spring MVC and login redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267809/spring-mvc-and-login-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for this task. You can configure Spring Security that it show every page only to loggedin users. If a not loggedin user try to access one of this protected pages, then spring security will redirect him to an logging page (your welcome page).